Looping with Ansible shell module takes long time
I have an Ansible task that looks like this:
    - name: Copy configs to destinations
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        mkdir -p {{ item.dest }}
        cp {{ cfg_dir }}/{{ item.cfg }} {{ item.dest }}
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      loop: "{{ cfg_to_dest_map }}"

When I execute it, it takes about 2-3 seconds to execute each item in cfg_to_dest_map.
cfg_to_dest_map looks like this:
cfg_to_dest_map:
  - cfg:  src/cfg1.cfg
    dest: /var/tmp1/cfg
  - cfg:  src/tmp2/cfg2.cfg
    dest: /usr/lib/tmp2/cfg
  ...

If cfg_to_dest_map contained hundreds or thousands of items, executing the task would take a very long time. Is there a way to improve this task so that it won't take a long time to execute?

Why wouldn't you use ansible.builtin.copy?

hi @Squashman, looping with ansible.builtin.copy is also very slow. also, i need to execute mkdir before cp.

@Squashman, i see that it is not necessary to mkdir since ansible.builtin.copy will automatically create the dir if it does not exist. however, upon testing the ansible.builtin.copy module, it takes about 5 seconds to copy each file to its destination.

Right, the observation you've described is a common issue. You could probably decrease the execution time with the already given answer or by changing your task and data structure. See in example How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook with regards to SSH connections? or How to optimize running speed of a playbook? or loop pointed directly at vars rather than expanding them first.

There are three directions to took.

You can use synchronize module to copy many files at instant (if they are not a big blobs).

You can move loop into shell, which will speed things up, or unroll loop into shell, see example below.

You can try use Mitogen for Ansible, which will speed things up for most cases, and break things in rare cases.


I advice you to try #1 before even thinking about other methods, because #1 is proper Ansible.
Loop unrolling:
    - name: Copy configs to destinations
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        mkdir -p {{ item.dest }}
        {% for item in cfg_to_dest_map %}
        cp {{ cfg_dir }}/{{ item.cfg }} {{ item.dest }}
        {% endfor %}
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash


hi @george-shuklin, thanks for the tips. i noticed though the synchronize module does not automatically create destination directories if they don't exist yet. it is also quite slow; a few seconds for each file copied. The loop unrolling I think is used with the template module, not shell.

You do a single synchronize, not a loop with many synchronizes. Also, you can use jinja in any module arguments, so my code should work. Try it.

I was able to make your loop unrolling code work. Thank you for your help. The mkdir line should be inside the for-loop.
I still can't imagine though on how to use a single synchronize to transfer multiple files in multiple unrelated subpaths to multiple unrelated destinations. Also, I don't think the synchronize module will automatically create the destination subdirectories.
